# Materialize.css Full Width Carousel Advice Needed

Tags: materialize

I am using MaterializeCSS Framework and i am trying to make my carousel to span full width of its parent container.

My carousel appears, but is very small. I read on the documentation that it can be made full width, but everything i try just breaks the carousel.

I tried this, but to no avail:

```
<script type="text/javascript">$(document).ready(function(){
$('.carousel').carousel full-width="true"();
});</script>
```

Any advice is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

i did like that 
`<div class="carousel carousel-slider">` 
but when i checked it on Google chrome i took

> url.indexOf is not a function

error like that
what is that meaning and what did i do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $('.carousel').carousel({
          full_width: true
      });
});
```

**EDIT:**

It's important to add class "carousel-slider", next to "carousel" div like:

```
<div class="carousel carousel-slider">
```

Comment: That's cause you got bootstrap container, just add "container-fluid" instead, like:
<div class="container-fluid" id="carousel-wrapper">

Answer (score 0):

That is because of jQuery 3.x.x, it works fine with jQuery 2.x.x. Hope it will save your time.